# PyQt4 QStringList with translatable option

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am making a multilanguage program.I heavily use the qt designer property system  and the QT linguist tool. There are an option for adding QStringList for property, and for a reason I don't want to translate them with Linguist. But there is no option to disabling it, for example the plain QtString has this option, so the Linguist ignore them. I think the QStringList uses translatable option by default.

Thanks

Comment: Which properties take a QStringList?

Comment: You can add strings in designer and it makes a list of string which I handle in my code. I am making a Taurus Like system which is uses the designer to create scada systems.

Comment: Sure, but _how_ exactly are you adding the strings? Give some _specific_ examples, so that others can see clearly what you're talking about.